# PHP Mail header for emails with special characters in the subject or message

Tags: php, email, character-encoding, header, mime

My code:

```
$to      = 'example@example.com';
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

When i send a mail with special characters such as `®ð-˚©-ʼ“æ,˚ˍðß©`,
in the message, it works but spacing is no longer dealt with (every new line or space gets removed)
And the second problem is that the special characters are not displayed in the subject.
They just output like: `ø&#700;ª&#700;`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Content-Type: text/html

If you set this header that means you have to send HTML to the user. You can either decide to use something like TinyMCE to let the user write the message in a Word-style editor and use the HTML output from that. Or set your headers to plaintext.

> Content-Type: text/plain

EDIT: Try this

```
$to      = 'example@example.com';
$subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
```

Comment: thanks, this solves the spacing problem and the caracters in the subject. The message however gives me something like: `¨®ð¥þƒ&#717;©&#711;&#730;`

Comment: Updated my answer with a suggestion to fix that issue as well. Let me know if it worked

Comment: this also keeps the spacing but outputs something like `����.�&#730;��&#730;` in both the subject and the message

Comment: couldn't it be that the request parameters you get are broken then? Try  var_dump($_REQUEST) and see what kind of data you get.

Comment: Is there any benefit in using \r\n over PHP_EOL?

Comment: @oelna allways use `PHP_EOL` to be shure you have right encoding.

Comment: @TFennis 10 years after your original answer, this still help me to configure headers and send beautiful mails :) Is that the beauty of Stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 3):

I have used this header and this is worked for me...

```
$headers = '';
$headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'.PHP_EOL;
$headers .= 'From: webmaster@example.com<From: webmaster@example.com>'.PHP_EOL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use mail() function. Use a fully crafted class that does (correctly) the job for you.

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/

Comment: When I see something like 'composer' or 'autoload' for a simple task like sending mails, I immediately close the tab. This is no solution, it's a ton of new problems.

Comment: When some hacker will exploit your mail() routine or all your email will go into spam, you'll reopen the tab :) Btw I'm using plain library, no auto load, no composer. Just 2 includes.

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is because special characters need "special" charset too.

Try changing the charset=ISO to charset=UTF8...

Also, PHP mail() functions works ok, but you will find a lot more benefits and options if you go for a better solution like [Swift Mailer](http://swiftmailer.org/)

Comment: Thanks, but by doing this i do get spacing right, but the output is like `�����&#717;�&#711;&#730;`

Comment: Be sure you are setting the right charset in the mail() funcion and also save the file in the same charset.