# Charset iso to utf8 in contact form

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a cms system, and Its contain a contact form...

```
            $body = ''.$contact_name.' ( <a href="mailto:'.$email.'">'.$email.'</a> ) has sent you a message,<br><br>
        ---------------------------------------------------------<br>
        '.htmlspecialchars (set_limit($_POST['message'],trim($config->message_length),'')).'<br>
        ---------------------------------------------------------<br><br>
        Referring Page: <a href="'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'">'.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'].'</a> IP Address: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].'';
```

Its the send message code, and my problem is, the site using ISO charset, but I want to use utf8 in the messages.. Now if I write éáőúűóüö, I get this in mail:

`éá&#337;ú&#369;óüö`

Any idea to fix this problem?

Comment: set proper header.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250140/php-mail-header

Comment: `$to      = 'somebody@something.com';
    $subject = $_REQUEST['subject'] ;
    $message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;
    $header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
    $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
    $header.= "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n"; 
    $header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);`

I have tryed this code, but after I add this, and I click on the "send" button my website doesnt answer.

Maybe need to modify this code? I think its doesnt fit with my cms.

Comment: any idea to fix this problem?