# How do I 'properly' add HTML to my current email output?

Tags: php, email, html-email

Below is the code for an email that my booking script outputs when somebody cancels their booking. I was wondering what the proper way to add HTML around the body of the email would be in this case. Is it as simple as adding the HTML around `$tempEmail->getEmailBody()`? If so, how would I do it with an include?

```
$customerEmailText = str_replace(
    array(
        "{USER}",
        "{UNIT_NAME}"
    ),
    array(
        $_SESSION['RNTLOGINUSERNAME'],
        $unit['name']
    ), 
    $tempEmail->getEmailBody()
);

$commonUtils->sendMail(
    $_SESSION['RNTLOGINUSEREMAIL'], 
    $customerEmailText, 
    $tempEmail->getSubject(), 
    $tempEmail->getFromEmail()
);
```

Comment: Since you're already using some form of email class, chances are it already provides a means to adapt the MIME type. Perhaps there is documentation on that even...

Comment: if you're using something like PHPMailer, then it's as simple as `$mailer->IsHTML(true)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is that easy, adding HTML to the email is the easy bit I suppose. Making it cross mail client would be difficult.

But I would leave that to you, after adding html you would also need to set the content type of the mail being sent. This usually defaults to plain/text, you would need to change that  to `text/html; charset=iso-8859-1`. This effectively is a header setting, since I see you are using a library to send emails, it should have a method for setting this header, the complete contents would be like:

```
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: and how does setting an http content header affect email...?

Comment: @MarcB Found this question which looks a bit similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250140/php-mail-header