# Change email headers on php send mail

Tags: php, email, plesk

I want to change my email headers on php mail send function , but i cant do this , i try use this into my php.ini

```
  sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail -t -i -f'user@domain.com'
```

but its not working , i use plesk .

then i try to change my php script and add headers Parameter into my php code [ im new at php and using someone's script on internet ] but its not working , i means the mail not sending ..

php send mail script with out any change work correctly and send email

```
<?php

    $emailTo = "user@domain.com";//change this to the email address which should receive the form data

    /*  
        NOTE: do not change anything below this
    */

    if( isset($_POST['maximus']) ) {

        //honey pot detection

        if( $_POST['maximus'] != '' ) {

            die('Bad spam bot!!');

        }

        $message = "";
        foreach( $_POST as $field => $val ) {

            if( $field != 'maximus' ) {

                $message .= $field . " : ". $val . "\n";

            }

        }

        $subject = $_POST['theSubject'];

        //send the email

        if( mail($emailTo, $subject, $message) ) {

            echo "Message sent!";

        } else {

            echo "Could not send message";

        }

    }

?>
```

but when i add headers parameter into my code the mail not sending

```
<?php

    $emailTo = "user@domain.com";//change this to the email address      which should receive the form data
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
$headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    /*  
        NOTE: do not change anything below this
    */

    if( isset($_POST['maximus']) ) {

        //honey pot detection

        if( $_POST['maximus'] != '' ) {

            die('Bad spam bot!!');

        }

        $message = "";
        // Always set content-type when sending HTML email

        foreach( $_POST as $field => $val ) {

            if( $field != 'maximus' ) {

                $message .= $field . " : ". $val . "\n";

            }

        }

        $subject = $_POST['theSubject'];

        //send the email

        if( mail($emailTo, $subject, $message, $headers) ) {

            echo "Message sent!";

        } else {

            echo "Could not send message";

        }

    }

?>
```

html form :

```
<form data-toggle="validator" method="post" action="form.php" id="quickQuoteForm" class="aSubmit">
                            <div style="display:none"><input type="text" name="maximus" value=""></div>
                            <input type="hidden" name="subject" value="Blue: Quick Quote Request">
                            <div class="contact-form-small">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="First and Last Name *" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" size="40" value="" name="name" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" placeholder="E-mail address" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" size="40" value="" name="email" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <select aria-invalid="false" name="service">
                                            <option value="Cargo">Cargo</option>
                                            <option value="Ground Transport">Ground Transport</option>
                                            <option value="Logistic Service">Logistic Service</option>
                                            <option value="Storage">Storage</option>
                                            <option value="Trucking Service">Trucking Service</option>
                                            <option value="Warehousing">Warehousing</option>
                                        </select>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="Subject *" aria-invalid="false" aria-required="true" size="40" value="" name="subject" required>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <textarea placeholder="Message *" aria-invalid="false" rows="10" cols="40" name="message" required></textarea>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-xs-12  col-md-12">
                                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" value="SEND MESSAGE">
                                        <img class="ajax-loader" id="loader" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Sending ..." style="display:none;">
                                    </div>
                                </div><!-- /.row -->
                                <div class="response success">Your message was sent; we'll be in touch shortly!</div>
                                <div class="response error">Unfortunately, we could not sent your message right now. Please try again.</div>
                            </div><!-- /.contact-form-small -->
                        </form>
```

i see this part of code **NOTE: do not change anything below this** but i really need to change my headers name ..

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250140/php-mail-header)

Comment: @chriz thank you for your reply , my problem is when i add headers parameter into my code , the email was not send , i want to solve this problem ..

Comment: Try arranging your headers as follows: https://pastebin.com/jiJ9JNdm